# Is there any way to upload Artifacts to the Apache ACE server without Web UI?

Tags: osgi, bndtools, apache-ace

We are working on an enterprise system writed by Java. And we use an Apache ACE server to deploy the OSGi bundles, a Jenkins as CI server. When we want to update a bundle, we make a jar file in Eclipse, and upload it to ACE server through Web UI. When we want to release a new version, we must upload all bundles through Web UI. I think that is foolish.
   I think there must be a simple way just like when I finish coding, then I can do something just in Elipse to upload the bundle to the ACE server. When we release a version, the Jenkins should also update all of the bundles to ACE server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you basically have two options if you want to automate things:

1. Use the REST based interface to talk to ACE.
2. Use the shell based interface to script to ACE.

Both are explained on the website, so for more detailed steps refer to:

1. http://ace.apache.org/docs/rest-api.html
2. http://ace.apache.org/docs/shell-api.html

Comment: Thank you. I've read rest-api, but when I tried to use POST http://myhost:8080/ace/work to check out, the return it's not the 302 but the page same with I visit in Web UI. Would you please show me a simple example about rest-api of ACE?